# Google Script - stuck in a search and write loop, without searching entire doc

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a script to run in a Google Spreadsheet that will scan a sheet in one spreadsheet, find every row that matches my IF, then write only those matching rows to another spreadsheet.
I'm extremely new to scripts altogether, but have pieced together something. 
What exactly, I'm not sure. 
It's a clunky mess, but I feel like its close to working.

Problems I run in to: (beyond not knowing a lick of javascript):

I don't feel that it searches the entire range of the source sheet.
It finds the first true condition, then keeps writing it to the target sheet. 
over. and over. and over.

Had a similar result using:

```
for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ 
if (data[n][13]=="yes"&&data[n][16]!="yes"){ ;
target.push(data[n]);
```

I eventually want to write in some duplicate checks and functions, but want to iron out the meat of it.

The meat:

```
function test() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0A....nc");
  var sh = source.getSheetByName("NA");
  var data=sh.getDataRange().getValues()

  var target=new Array();
  for(i=0;i<data.length;++i){ 
  for (j=0;j<data[i].length;++j){
    if (data[i][13]=="yes"&&data[i][16]==""){ ;
      target.push(data[i]);
}
}
if(target.length>0){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0A....Gc");   
  var sh2=SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Sheet5")); 
  var xx = sh2.getLastRow();
  sh2.getRange(xx+1,1,target.length,target[0].length).setValues(target);
  }
}
}
```

Thanks for any help anyone can offer!

EDIT: managed to get something to work exactly like I'd like.

```
function testtest() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0A....Wc");
  var sh = source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0A....mc");   
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var xx = sh2.getLastRow();


  var target=new Array();
  for(i=0;i<data.length;++i){ 
    if (((data[i][13]=='yes')||(data[i][13]=='YES')||(data[i][13]=='Yes')) && !((data[i][16]=='yes')||(data[i][16]=='YES')||(data[i][16]=='Yes'))){
      target.push(data[i]);}

}

   var newData=new Array();
   for(i in target){
    var sh2D = sh2.getDataRange().getValues();
    var row = target[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in sh2D){
      if(row.join() == sh2D[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
     }
     if(!duplicate){
       newData.push(row);
    }
  }

   if(newData.length>0){ 

   var dest = sh2.getRange(xx+1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length);
      dest.setValues(newData);
   }
}
```

Yes, it's sloppy.
Now working on being able to update a cell in my new target sheet and translate that change to the master list. Actually, its just adding a "yes" to a column when work is complete, then updating the master (on a sheet that gets constantly sorted by 25+ people).

Oh, and if anyone knows a way to search for "yes" independent of case or extra spaces, it'd certainly help clean up my IF line.

Comment: As an FYI, Stack Overflow is geared towards clear question/answer technical questions. For show & tell or broad advice you may have more success on an Apps Script Google+ Community. See our support page for more information: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support

Comment: Do you know where the loop is stucked?
To compare YES case independent just add toUpperCase. For example:
data[i][13].toUpperCase() == "YES"

Answer (score 1):

> Oh, and if anyone knows a way to search for "yes" independent of case or extra spaces, it'd certainly help clean up my IF line.

Just do what you said... compare upper case values, and trim whitespace.

```
if ((data[i][13].trim().toUpperCase() === 'YES') && (data[i][16].trim().toUpperCase() != 'YES')) {
  ...
```

If you need to do this a lot, create a helper function:

```
/**
 * Perform case-insensitive, trimmed comparison of two strings.
 * Returns true if strings are nominally equal.
 */
function strEqual(str1, str2) {
  var one = str1.trim().toUpperCase();
  var two = str2.trim().toUpperCase();
  return one === two;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
if (strEqual(data[i][13],'yes') && !strEqual(data[i][16],'YeS')) {
  ...
```